# How can i display correctly my image-gallery using h2

Tags: html, css, width, margin, image-gallery

So im working on a gallery of image that can be scrolled vertically with centered and equally espace images, and when the mouse pass hover, the image scale up and a title show up.
To make it work, i use an

```
h2
```

with a

```
background-image
```

But when i put it all together, the h2 just collapse next to each other.

This is the way i want it to look
[image]

but this is what i get for now
[image]

My code for now is this
HTML :

```
<div id="gallery">
                            <h2 style="background-image: url(img/image-presentation.jpg);">
                                Concert</h2>
                            <h2 style="background-image: url(img/image-presentation.jpg);">
                                Concert</h2>
                            <h2 style="background-image: url(img/image-presentation.jpg);">
                                Concert</h2>
                            <h2 style="background-image: url(img/image-presentation.jpg);">
                                Concert</h2>
                            <h2 style="background-image: url(img/image-presentation.jpg);">
                                Concert</h2>
                            <h2 style="background-image: url(img/image-presentation.jpg);">
                                Concert</h2>
                        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#projet .content .window #gallery {
    text-align: center;
    height: 40vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 5vh;
    padding-top: 1vh;
    padding-bottom: 1vh;
    display: block;
}

#projet .content .window #gallery h2 {
    width: 25vh;
    height: 25vh;
    border-radius: 1vh;
    margin: 1.5vh;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: transparent;

    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

#projet .content .window #gallery h2:hover {    
    color: black;    
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

I dont know what to do or what i am doing wrong.

Can someone help me ?

I tried different display in css in the

```
#gallery
```

but i couldnt find a correct way to make it work

Comment: display:table-cell keeps then in a single row , so they shrink since parent is a block. Also margin is not avalaible . Use inline-block maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the "background-image" of an `<h2>` tag is not the right way to do what you want. You should create a `<div>` where inside you put an `<img>` for the image and an `<h2>` for the text. Or you can use pseudo-elements on the image instead of the `<h2>` and the `<div>`. To put them however you want, you can use either `display: grid;` or `display: flex;`.

I tried to write on the spot as it should be one of the possibilities.

**HTML**

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="img/image-presentation.jpg" alt="image">
        <h2>My Title<h2>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="img/image-presentation.jpg" alt="image">
        <h2>My Title<h2>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="img/image-presentation.jpg" alt="image">
        <h2>My Title<h2>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="img/image-presentation.jpg" alt="image">
        <h2>My Title<h2>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="img/image-presentation.jpg" alt="image">
        <h2>My Title<h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#projet .content .window #gallery {
    display: grid;
    column-gap: 50px;
    row-gap: 50px;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
}

.image-container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 1s;
    z-index: 10;
}

.image-container img:hover {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
}

.image-container h2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    opacity: 0;
}

.image-container img:hover+h2 {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use separate div for every image instead of using image as a background-imgage for h2 tag,like this:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="img/image-presentation.jpg" alt="image">
        <h2>Concert<h2>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="img/image-presentation.jpg" alt="image">
        <h2>Concert<h2>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="img/image-presentation.jpg" alt="image">
        <h2>Concert<h2>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="img/image-presentation.jpg" alt="image">
        <h2>Concert<h2>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="img/image-presentation.jpg" alt="image">
        <h2>Concert<h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

For CSS, you can use flex, like this:

```
#gallery{
    display:flex;
    width: 80%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
.image{width: 33%}
```